# Confused Email server

Tags: postfix

I have recently migrated my server from Centos 6.9 to a new server with Centos 7.9 and I faced numerous issues owing to drastic change in OS, Version Changes in Perl, Python, PHP and Apache. I have sorted them out.

Except that the Postfix/Dovecot servers continue to cause deep anguish.
For example: `admin@domain1.com`, `admin@domain2.com` and `admin@domain3.com` - all land up in the admin account of the server which is not mapped to any domain in the first place.

This is what I have done in the `/ect/postfix/virtual`:

```
admin@domain1.com domain1.com-admin
admin@domain2.com domain2.com-admin
```

Result: No joy

Then I added into `/etc/postfix/vmailbox`:

```
admin@domain1.com domain1.com/admin
admin@domain2.com domain2.com/admin
```

After doing the routine postmap /etc/postfix/virtual and postmap /etc/postfix/vmailbox, still no separation of the admin mails.

Where should I look ? I would be grateful for any pointers.

Postfix configuration information:

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
command_directory = /usr/sbin
config_directory = /etc/postfix
daemon_directory = /usr/libexec/postfix
data_directory = /var/lib/postfix
debug_peer_level = 2
debugger_command = PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin ddd $daemon_directory/$process_name $process_id & sleep 5
disable_vrfy_command = yes
header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/header_checks
home_mailbox = Maildir/
html_directory = no
inet_protocols = all
mailbox_command = /usr/bin/procmail-wrapper -o -a $DOMAIN -d $LOGNAME
mailbox_size_limit = 0
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq.postfix
manpage_directory = /usr/share/man
milter_default_action = accept
mydestination = $myhostname, $mydomain, localhost.$mydomain, localhost, mail.$mydomain
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases.postfix
non_smtpd_milters = inet:localhost:8891
readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.10.1/README_FILES
resolve_dequoted_address = no
sample_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.10.1/samples
sender_bcc_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/bcc
sender_dependent_default_transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/dependent
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix
setgid_group = postdrop
smtp_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_error_sleep_time = 5s
smtpd_milters = inet:localhost:8891
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated reject_unauth_destination
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
smtpd_tls_CAfile = /etc/postfix/postfix.ca.pem
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/postfix/postfix.cert.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/postfix/postfix.key.pem
smtpd_tls_mandatory_protocols = !SSLv2, !SSLv3, !TLSv1, !TLSv1.1
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
virtual_mailbox_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/vmailbox
```

Snippet from `/etc/postfix/virtual`:

```
domain1.com domain1.com
admin@domain1.com domain1.com-admin
domain2.com domain2.com
admin@domain2.com domain2.com-admin
```

Snippet from `/etc/postfix/vmailbox`:

```
admin@domain1.com domain1.com/admin
admin@domain2.com domain2.com/admin
```

Comment: Please provide your postfix configuration.

Comment: Thanks Schneider.alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
command_directory = /usr/sbin
config_directory = /etc/postfix
daemon_directory = /usr/libexec/postfix
data_directory = /var/lib/postfix
debug_peer_level = 2
debugger_command = $process_id & sleep 5
disable_vrfy_command = yes
header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/header_checks
home_mailbox = Maildir/
html_directory = no
inet_protocols = all
mailbox_command = /usr/bin/procmail-wrapper -o -a $DOMAIN -d $LOGNAME

Comment: mailbox_size_limit = 0
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq.postfix
manpage_directory = /usr/share/man
milter_default_action = accept
mydestination = $myhostname, $mydomain, localhost.$mydomain, localhost, mail.$mydomain
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases.postfix
sender_dependent_default_transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/dependent
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated reject_unauth_destination
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks

Comment: permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
smtpd_tls_CAfile = /etc/postfix/postfix.ca.pem
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/postfix/postfix.cert.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/postfix/postfix.key.pem
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual

Comment: Please edit this information into your question. It's unreadable in the comments.

Comment: Upgrading Postfix should in most cases continue to work with the old configuration. Unless you show us your pre-upgrade backup and the changes you made, it will be almost impossible to guess which change caused undesirable side-effects.

Comment: What are `myhostname`, `mydomain`, `myorigin`? Do you realize what happens when you specify destination without "@domain" in the alias maps database? (It [appends @$myorigin](https://www.postfix.org/virtual.5.html) [by default](https://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#append_at_myorigin).) When you provide a Postfix configuration, you should follow a suggestion given in the tag description; it will make sure you include all the needed information.

Comment: Thank you Nikita. The problem is when I migrated, obviously the Webmin/Virtualmin has munged some critical data. I have checked your link and all it says is the content of the virtual table should have the admin@domain.com address . But it does not specify how the address should look like. myhostname points to the main server name and mydomain refers to the virtual domains. What do I miss ?

Comment: I have managed to restore normalcy by editing the /etc/postfix/virtual: The order is list your virtual domain [tab] virtual domain, user@domain[tab] user\@domain. Follow the drill to update the virtual table and reload.